# Excel - extracting data based on another list

Tags: excel, extract

I have an Excel worksheet with two columns (name/ID) and then another list that is a subset of the names only from the larger aforementioned list. I want to go through the subset list and then pull the data from the larger list (name/ID) and put it somewhere else...essentially only grabbing the data from the larger list if the name is on the subset.

I tried using Filters, but couldn't get it work. Thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

New Excel versions

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,B,B,1,FALSE)),"",A1)`

Older Excel versions

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1;B:B;1;FALSE));"";A1)`

That is: "If the value of A1 exists in the B column, display it here. If it doesn't exist, leave it empty."

Comment: I've tried using this, but am thinking I am doing something wrong. I have my data arranged as such:


List A - List B - Status - Number


I edited the formula to this:
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,B$1:D$8371,1,FALSE)),"",A1)


If the values in list A exist in list B I want to display the entry in List B along with status and the number.


Thoughts? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: To have a number and a function on that number in the same column, you'll need to include the number in the function. That means you'd have to exchange "B$1:D$8371" with a number for each line. An easier and more flexible solution is to do one thing in each column, for example values in A & B, =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,B$1:D$8371,1,FALSE)),"",A1) in C, the status in D, and the concatenation of C and D in E (or wherever you want to display it).

Comment: This is a very old question/answer but just to make it clear in case someone else gets momentarily confused - the answer has ";" when it needs ",".

Comment: @MikeBaz: That depends on your locale, unfortunately. `;` is used in much of Europe since `,` is the decimal separator.

Answer (score 12):

I couldn't get the first method to work, and I know this is an old topic, but this is what I ended up doing for a solution:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,B:B,0)),"Not Matched", A1)
```

Basically, MATCH A1 to Column B exactly (the 0 stands for match exactly to a value in Column B).  ISNA tests for #N/A response which match will return if the no match is found.  Finally, if ISNA is true, write "Not Matched" to the selected cell, otherwise write the contents of the matched cell.

Comment: This worked for me perfectly! If anybody needs it for Spanish excel this is the translated formula: =SI(ESNOD(COINCIDIR(A2;B:B;0));"No concuerda";A2)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Advanced Filter? Using your short list as the 'Criteria' and long list as the 'List Range'. Use the options: 'Filter in Place' and 'Unique Values'.

You should be presented with the list of unique values that only appear in your short list.

Alternatively, you can paste your Unique list to another location (on the same sheet), if you prefer. Choose the option 'Copy to another Location' and in the 'Copy to' box enter the cell reference (say F1) where you want the Unique list.

Note: this will work with the two columns (name/ID) too, if you select the two columns as both 'Criteria' and 'List Range'.

Answer (score 1):

I have been hasseling with that as other folks have.

I used the criteria;

`=countif(matchingList,C2)=0`

where matchingList is the list that i am using as a filter.

have a look at this

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x47VFMhRLnM&list=PL63A7644FE57C97F4&index=30

The trick i found is that normally you would have the column heading in the criteria matching the data column heading. this will not work for criteria that is a formula.

What I found was if I left the column heading blank for only the criteria that has the `countif` formula in the advanced filter works. If I have the column heading i.e. the column heading for column C2 in my formula example then the filter return no output.

Hope this helps